# Do iterative formula only solve for one positive root?

Tags: fixed-point-theorems, iterated-function-system

For all the questions I have done using an iterative formula, the quadratic equation only ever solves to **one** root, I am not sure is this always the case, or is there a method to find multiple roots? Also, my teacher said that the iterative formula always gives the **positive** root, is this true?

Also, with solving using an iterative formula, does the starting value of $x$ matter? Will they still converge to the same value?

Please could someone explain simply please, I am fairly new to this concept. Thanks

Comment: Consider the Babylonian iterative scheme for roots of $x^2-2$.  That is, $x\mapsto \frac 12\times \left( x+\frac 2x\right)$.  If you start with $-3$ you converge to $-\sqrt 2$.

Comment: @lulu ok, so the iterative formula can lead to negative roots, but it only solves for one root right?

Comment: I don't understand.  Of course if you start with a particular value you  get one solution (trusting that the process converges).  But, with the example I gave, you get one root if you start with $-3$ and the other root if you start with $3$.

Comment: @lulu oh okay I didn't notice that, its just that for some of the questions I am doing for example, it asks you to '' find the positive root of the equation $x^2-7x-3=0$ using the iterative formula $x=7+\frac{3}{x}$ where $x=7$ ''. So I thought it was only possible to find only one root of the equation because then I tried different starting values of $x$ and it still seemed to converge to the same value so I just thought you could only solve for the positive root, but im guessing this is all wrong?

Comment: Yes, that's wrong.  That equation isn't all that different from $x^2-2=0$, you just have to argue that the process converges to the positive root from some specified starting point.